# Powershell - Parsing CSV for substring

Tags: powershell, csv

Trying to learn how to use Powershell to help with pulling data from various sources and banging my head on a poorly formed CSV. I have a CSV that just has a text string in the first cell of each row. Each row has a hash of a file, some data and the hash of the program that wrote it. I need to extract the first hash after "link hash=" below to another file.

```
[enter code here][1]
```

If the image doesn't work the first lines read:

```
The file "<share><link hash="randomhash1">C:\random\location\file.exe</link></share>" was first detected on a local disk. The file was created by the application "<share><link hash="differenthash">C:\windows\explorer.exe</link></share>".
The file "<share><link hash="randomhash2">C:\random\location\file.exe</link></share>" was first detected on a local disk. The file was created by the application "<share><link hash="differenthash">C:\windows\explorer.exe</link></share>".
The file "<share><link hash="randomhash3">C:\random\location\file.exe</link></share>" was first detected on a local disk. The file was created by the application "<share><link hash="differenthash">C:\windows\explorer.exe</link></share>".
The file "<share><link hash="randomhash4">C:\random\location\file.exe</link></share>" was first detected on a local disk. The file was created by the application "<share><link hash="differenthash">C:\windows\explorer.exe</link></share>".
```

I have been looking for a way to tell powershell to give me the value for "hash=" "" in a new CSV, but hitting syntax errors and obviously just doing it tremendously wrong. As I am trying to learn this, if somebody could state this is the regex and why I would be eternally grateful.

Below is what I have tried. Looking at Select-String I have a knowledge gap on how to get the regex match to become an object I can output. If I take out the ForEach-Object argument I get a csv with a true statement for each line.

Import-Csv C:\Users\me\Desktop\Bad_hash.csv | Select-string -Pattern "(?\w+)" | ForEach-Object {$hash = $_.Matches[0].Groups['hash'].Value [PSCustomObject] @{ Hash = $hash}} | | Export-Csv C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.csv

Comment: You have not included any code or example data. Please update your question with sample CSV data as well as the script/code you are using as well as the output you are expecting.

Comment: Check out [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: Your update only has the text you're looking for, which is good, but we really need a sample of the CSV file (shortened to a few lines and redacted appropriately, of course). You also haven't posted the script/code you are using to attempt to parse it.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - Thanks I have been poking at Select-String to see if I could figure this out. Only about a month into learning PowerShell. I have put in what I have been working on.

Comment: You still not have included a CSV sample.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - I am not sure what you are looking for. It is above. It is 100 rows with different variations of "The file..." I have listed. If I post additional rows, it will be similar rows that says the exact same thing with a different hash. Not trying to be difficult but the file is just that repeated 100 times with different hashes I need to extract.

Comment: I am looking for what I already said: a _sample of the CSV data_ (redacted appropriately). You do not need to post all of it; just the header row and a few rows of representative data. (Otherwise, it's just guesswork for those who might answer, as we don't have any sample data!)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - I have given what StackOverflow will allow me to post being a new user. If I could attach a copy of the scrubbed csv I would, but not seeing a way to do so. As mentioned above there is no column information. Its a poorly formed CSV that has all of the data entered into the first cell of each row only utilizing the first column. I would assume I could tell PowerShell to look for "link hash" and print the values behind it. I am okay if we accidentally pick up the explorer.exe hash in the same line as duplicates will automatically remove when I feed it into my larger dataset.

Comment: All you need to do is update your question and use code format (4 space indent) with a few sample lines, including the header row. (No images please; use copy and paste, indenting 4 spaces.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - It won't let me do that as a new account. it keeps changing it to an image. It pops up a reason saying that I can't do it until I have been here longer. I put in the code block above what the first four lines are. There are no headers, no additional columns.

Comment: 1) Open your CSV file in a plain-text editor (such as Notepad). 2) Select the first few lines of the CSV file and copy them to the clipboard. 3) Edit your question and paste the lines into your question. Insert 4 spaces at the front of each line. That's it.

Comment: Are you saying that the 4 lines you have included in your code are your CSV file? If so, that's just a text file and _not_ a CSV file. CSV means "comma separated values" and is a way to express multi-column data in a textual format. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Select-String -pattern is your RegEx friend when Import-Csv isn't a viable option.
I'd be more helpful if I had samples.

Comment: Updated the string, sorry for the delay as I was called off for other stuff.